# OpenSSL Libarary: ECDSA: How to convert uncompressed public key to compressed`

Tags: openssl

I have the compressed public key and would like to convert it to an uncompressed public key. That is how I get the keys:

```
EC_KEY *key_pair_obj = nullptr;

BIGNUM *priv_key;

EC_POINT *pub_key;

EC_GROUP *secp256k1_group;

char *priv_key_char;
char *pub_key_char;
char *pub_key_char_comp;

int ret_error;

// Generate secp256k1 key pair
key_pair_obj = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
ret_error    = EC_KEY_generate_key(key_pair_obj);

// Get private key
priv_key      = (BIGNUM *)EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key_pair_obj);
priv_key_char = BN_bn2hex(priv_key);

// Get public key
pub_key            = (EC_POINT *)EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key_pair_obj);
secp256k1_group    = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
pub_key_char       = EC_POINT_point2hex(secp256k1_group, pub_key, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, nullptr);

EC_GROUP_free(secp256k1_group);

printf("Private key        : %s\n\n", priv_key_char);
printf("Public key uncomp. : %s\n", pub_key_char_comp);
```

I know that I could use:

```
pub_key_char_comp  = EC_POINT_point2hex(secp256k1_group, pub_key, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, nullptr);
```

... but I would like to convert it later. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The text of your question is backwards from your title and example. Assuming the latter:

Given the hex representation of the uncompressed form of a public point (or indeed any point) *on a prime-field curve* like secp256k1, which is of a form like

```
 u = "04xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy" // with lengths depending on curve's field
```

to create the hex representation of the compressed form do something like:

```
 int k = strlen(u)/4; // hexit-pairs (value bytes) of each coordinate
 // or use known constant for curve e.g. 32 for secp256k1 
 char * c = malloc (k*2+2+1); // error handling needed but depends on program
 memcpy (c+2, u+2, k*2); // copy x
 memcpy (c, u[k*4+1] & 1? "03": "02", 2); // set first byte per low bit of y
 c[k*2+2] = '\0'; // string terminator
```

Or if you don't need to keep the uncompressed form you can more simply re-use its OpenSSL_malloc'ed space (albeit wasting some of it):

```
 u[1] = '2' | u[k*4+1] & 1; 
 // leave u[0] and u[2..k*2+1] alone
 u[k*2+2] = '\0';
```